# Solve nonlinear differential equations with some Eliminations

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems

In these sets of equations and elims, `Eliminate` is not able to handle nonlinearity, so it does not give an answer for the desired output. Any suggestions? (I excluded a2[t],a2'[t],a2''[t] from elimination list to help it proceed)

```
equat := {M == T1 + J1*a1''[t],
T2 == J2*a2''[t] + k*(a2[t] - x[t]) + d*(a2'[t] - x'[t]),
a1[t] == a2[t], a1'[t] == a2'[t], a1''[t] == a2''[t], T1 == T2, x[t] == (2*pi/c)*y[t],
x'[t] == (2*pi/c)*y'[t], x''[t] == (2*pi/c)*y''[t],
y[t] == z[t] - p*Cos[U[t]], y'[t] == z'[t] + p*U'[t]*Sin[U[t]],
y''[t] == z''[t] + p*U''[t]*Sin[U[t]] + p*(U'[t]^2)*Cos[U[t]],
U[t] == ArcSin[r[t]/b],
U'[t] == (r'[t])/(b*(1 - ((r[t])^2)/b^2)^(1/2)),
U''[t] == r''[t]/(b*(1 - ((r[t])^2)/(b^2))^(1/2)) +
(r[t]*(r'[t])^2)/(b^3*(1 - ((r[t])^2)/(b^2))^(3/2))}

elim := {x[t], x'[t], x''[t], U[t], U'[t], U''[t], y[t], y'[t],y''[t], T1, T2}

First@Solve[(Eliminate[equat, elim] // FullSimplify) /. a1 -> a2, {a1''[t]}]
```

it results in empty, while there is an answer manually. And it gives two error messages as:

```
Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
Solve::fulldim: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
```

I should note that I am after an answer for `a1''[t]` as a function of `r[t]`, `r'[t]`, `z[t]` and `z'[t]`. Thanks.
I should also mention that I cannot change the format of equation list.

Comment: Why are you not using `DSolve[]`?

Comment: Because Dsolve is for finding a solution for a differential equation. For example having a differential equation for a1''[t] and asking for a solution for a1[t]. In this example I am not after a solution, the aim is to eliminate some variables and find a1''[t] with respect to the rest of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Solve[Eliminate[{M == T1 + J1*a1''[t], 
    T2 == J2*a2''[t] + k*(a2[t] - x[t]) + d*(a2'[t] - x'[t])} //. {a1 -> a2, T1 -> T2, 
    x -> Function[t, (2*pi/c)*y[t]], y -> Function[t, z[t] - p*Cos[U[t]]], 
    U -> Function[t, ArcSin[r[t]/b]]}, T2], a2''[t]]
```

---

**Update**

OK, if `equat` can't be modified, how about

```
rule = Cases[equat, (lhs : Alternatives @@ elim) == rhs_ :> (lhs -> rhs)];
Solve[DeleteCases[equat /. a1 -> a2 //. rule, True], a2''[t], 
 Complement[elim, rule[[All, 1]]]]
```

or a bit simpler:

```
rule = Rule @@@ Cases[equat, Alternatives @@ elim == _];
Solve[And @@ (equat /. a1 -> a2 //. rule), a2''[t], Complement[elim, rule[[All, 1]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and I see you excluded some nonlinear equations from list of equations. But I cannot extract those from equations since all of the equations are sent from Matlab to be solved in Mathematica and the solution will be read back in Matlab. So the process will be automatic and I cannot intervene in equations list. I guess there should be a way not to separate equations.

Comment: @fr …You mean the equation system is deduced by MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, my differential equations are produced in Matlab. @xzczd

Comment: @fr If the nonlinear equation always have the structure like `y[t]=……` i.e. the function or derivative of the function is on the left hand side of the equation, it's possible to extract the equation with program. Is that so?

Comment: Yes that is true, the format of the functions are always the same. But I cannot predict nonlinear equations and number of them in different systems. This was just very simplified version of equation list that I can have. They are usually much more complex. @xzczd

Comment: @fr Is `elim` manually defined, or sent from MATLAB and unchangable?

Comment: the structure of elims is the same, but I can reduce some variables or add extra to it. @xzcxd

Comment: @fr Check my edit.

Comment: Did you get an answer from this? It gives several error messages for me!
Complement::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Complement[elim,{}]. >>
Solve::bdomv: Warning: Complement[elim,{}] is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>
Solve::naqs: equat is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>
@xzczd

Comment: @fr Of course: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g2rN.png

Comment: I could not add a photo in comment! so I edited your answer with the result I am getting. @xzczd

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC6BH.png <- I bet now you find my first solution doesn't work, either. You have (probably unintentionally) cleared `equat` and `elim` between `In[2]` and `In[18]`, see the color of them? If a variable is blue, then there's no value stored in it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to to not use functions, but just normal variables.

```
rep = {a1 -> a2, a2''[t] -> appt, a2'[t] -> apt, a2[t] -> at, 
   x''[t] -> xppt, x'[t] -> xpt, x[t] -> xt, y''[t] -> yppt, 
   y'[t] -> ypt, y[t] -> yt, z''[t] -> zppt, z'[t] -> zpt, z[t] -> zt,
    r''[t] -> rppt, r'[t] -> rpt, r[t] -> rt, U''[t] -> uppt, 
   U'[t] -> upt, U[t] -> ut};
revrep = Rest[Reverse /@ rep];
```

Solve:

```
FullSimplify@Solve[Quiet@Eliminate[equat/.rep, elim/.rep], appt] /. revrep
```

> `{{(a2^′′)[t] -> (
>      1/((J1 + 
>        J2)^2))(-(J1 + J2) (-M + k a2[t] + d Derivative[1][a2][t]) - (
>        2 Sqrt[c^2 d^2 (J1 + J2)^2 p^2 pi^2 (b^2 - r[t]^2) Sin[
>           U[t]]^2 Derivative[1][r][t]^2])/(c^2 (b^2 - r[t]^2)) + (
>        2 (J1 + J2) pi (-k p Cos[U[t]] + k z[t] + 
>           d Derivative[1][z][t]))/c)}, {(a2^′′)[t] -> (
>      1/((J1 + 
>        J2)^2))(-(J1 + J2) (-M + k a2[t] + d Derivative[1][a2][t]) + (
>        2 Sqrt[c^2 d^2 (J1 + J2)^2 p^2 pi^2 (b^2 - r[t]^2) Sin[
>           U[t]]^2 Derivative[1][r][t]^2])/(c^2 (b^2 - r[t]^2)) + (
>        2 (J1 + J2) pi (-k p Cos[U[t]] + k z[t] + 
>           d Derivative[1][z][t]))/c)}}`

Comment: This works also, thanks. But, you changed the format of equations list completely, I cannot intervene and make any changes in equations, since they are being sent by Matlab. @Feyre

Comment: Interesting. I guess you're in v11? It doesn't work in v9.

Comment: Mine is 10.4 @xzczd

Comment: @FR I edited my question to prevent the changes to the lists.

Comment: @xzczd Both `10.4` and `11`, I'm actually surprised this doesn't work on `9`.